How to organize signing process of docker images in CI pipe?
Good afternoon.
We have a container image development and assembly infrastructure built on Gitlab. The developer develops the code and commits it to GitLab. The container image is assembled using GitLab-runner mechanisms. We are using the free version of Gitlab, and we do not have the option to use the commercial version. For this reason, we cannot use multiple "approves" for the same code.

Before assembling the container image, SCA, code review, and SAST are checked.
After the container image is built, it is uploaded to the image storage of the development environment (local Docker hub DEV).
After the container image is assembled, the container is launched in a test environment and DAST testing is performed.
After testing, the image is copied to the storage of the product environment (local Docker hub PROD).

The question is : we want to ensure that at each of the steps of passing the container image through the pipe, a process of approving works for its further passage. For example, a code review occurs first. The team makes a code review and puts an "approve", after which the image goes for further checks. Further, similarly with SCA, SAST, DUST, etc.  If the tests are automatic, then according to the successful results of passing the automatic test, the "approve" should be set automatically. After passing all the tests, a runner should be called, which will check that all the necessary applications have been received and run the "cosign" utility to sign the container and upload the container to the storage of the product environment (local Docker hub PROD).
Please tell me how we could be organize such a process?
Thank you.
I tried to offer using comments in GitLab for approving, but team took this as bad idea.

What about :

using separate CI pipelines for the steps and benefitting from the Gitlab's downstream pipelines.
setting up manual validation for specific jobs, so that the pipeline will block until a manual "click on a button" is performed by a developer.
using custom Gitlab variables ($SHOULD_THE_NEXT_STEP_RUN or $IS_SOME_TEST_OK = True / False), that would be set in one job and checked against in the following jobs.

